# Invoke a function that receives a function to get a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a function similar to this:

```
  public getNumberOfAvailableColumns(): (rowIndex: number) => number {
    return (rowIndex) => rowIndex + 10
  }
```

Then I'm trying to send it as props and immediately invoke it to get the value:

```
<Observed
  numberOfAvailableColumns={getNumberOfAvailableColumns(() => 3)}
```

I receive the ts error:

```
type '(rowIndex: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

(I simplified the functions just for the example)
What would be the correct syntax in order to execute the function and get the value `13` ?

Please note: I'm constructing the function this way for mobX, if it looks convoluted

Comment: As the error already says. `getNumberOfAvailableColumns()` expects a number and not a function.

Comment: Should not it be like `getNumberOfAvailableColumns(3)()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`getNumberOfAvailableColumns`  return function, so it should be

```
<Observed
  numberOfAvailableColumns={getNumberOfAvailableColumns()(3)}
```

Because it's returning function and you trying to assign a function to number here

```
type '(rowIndex: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'number'
```